# How to give different style with css if 2 pages have same id?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

in same site i have a page disclaimer 2 times in 2 different section

corporate > disclaimer.html
consumer > disclaimer.html

one good this my company's custom cms is generates body `id` for each page

but the problem here is he generate `id` as same as page name, and i can't change name and can't give different `ID`

both pages having same id `<body id="disclaimer">`

and

i want to apply 2 different style to `<p>` to both pages

like

for corporate > disclaimer.html i need this `p { color:#666}`

for consumer > disclaimer.html i need this `p { color:#000}`

how to do this, is there any pure css way ? if it's not possible with pure css then give me jquery solution.

**update:**

i can't add per page basis css file in `<head>`.

Comment: you should remove the jquery tag because as you said you need a pure css way to solve the problem!

Comment: What _can_ you do per page? Can you wrap the content in an element that you can name? So corporate > disclaimer is wrapped in `<div id="corporate_disclaimer">` and consumer in `<div id="consumer_disclaimer">`. You have to get tricksy to work around the limitations of your CMS.

Comment: MDCore - no i can't wrap

Comment: Simple, if are two different pages, just use the tag style or the property style, in div you want customize

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like you can do anything with pure CSS if the pages are identical except for the URL.

So pseudocode for a basic javascript solution:

```
var path, section, body;
path = window.location.pathname;
section = parseToSection(path);
body = window.document.body;
if ('corporate' === section){
    body.addClass('corporate');
} else if ('consumer' === section){
    body.addClass('consumer');
}
```

and then add rules like the following to your css:

```
body.corporate p{
    color:#666
}

body.consumer p{
    color:#000;
}
```

In your solution you might want to use jquery's element selectors instead of directly using the window object. Also writing the code for the `parseToSection()` function is up to you.

Comment: this is not pure CSS it's javascript + css!

Comment: by gosh, I think you're right! Maybe it's because there is nothing he can do in pure CSS with the restrictions he has! Good thing he also asked for a javascript solution.

Comment: yeah, you're right. i've noticed it later. i even deleted my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you just fetch two different css files on them?

Comment: u mean inline or in page css no , and i can only add external css and only in common header.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare three css files:

1. for everything that's the same for all pages,
2. for the Consumer-specific styles
3. for the Corporate-specific styles

All pages will reference [1], then either [2] or [3] depending on which is relevant.

Comment: i know this but the problem due to some reasons i can't add per page basis css

Answer (score 0):

it's easy in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var color = (document.location.pathname.match(/corporate/)) ? "#666" : "#000";
  $("body#disclaimer p").css("color", color);
}
```

but with pure CSS I think it is not possible.